# Tagged parameter not working as described in documentation

Tags: bug, tags, search, api-v2.3

In the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) it is reported that the tagged parameter in the request URL should work like this:

> tagged - a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which at least one will be present on all returned questions.

But if I use a list of tags, only questions that include ALL of the listed tags are returned.
For example, if I make a request for this URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&views=50&site=stackoverflow&tagged=java;javascript;python

the results returned are only 60, the questions that include ALL of the 3 tags, java, javascript and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; because the API doesn't have much priority for the developers, here is a workaround: use the `q` parameter and set it to `[java] or [javascript] or [python]`.

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%5Bjava%5D%20or%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20or%20%5Bpython%5D&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

This is the same syntax as you can use on the site's search page:
[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+or+[javascript]+or+[python]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+or+%5Bjavascript%5D+or+%5Bpython%5D)